# SQL order by when has a tie

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: The description of the problem is shown in the following image]

```
SELECT id, title, reserved_tickets
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
   ON table a.id=b.id
ORDER BY 
    reserved_tickets DESC
    ,CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN id END ASC
```

Could someone assess my code or help me improve?

Comment: Did you try running your query? If you did, what was the result?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sort by id first, then tickets**

```
ORDER BY a.id, b.reserved_tickets
```

---

**You should also qualify all of your fields with the proper table identifier**

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, b.reserved_tickets
```

Comment: NO! The requirements specify to order by tickets then by id. But the clause "CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN id END ASC"  is unnecessary, for 2 reasons. First, the default sort  order when nulls are involved is nulls last. Second, in this case, the column to be sorted cannot be null as it's defined as not null. So the sorting becomes just "Order by b.reserved_tickets desc, a.id"